# Garbage collection inside a lock object

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, deadlock

Putting peoples opinions about garbage collection aside are there any deadlocking issues with the following:

```
private static readonly object lockObj = new object();
lock(lockObj )
{
           ///Load objects into a cache List<object> from DB call 
           GC.Collect(2);
           GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
           GC.Collect(2);
}
```

Comment: Why would you be doing that? Regardless, don't call GC.Collect() ... 99/100 you are doing it for the wrong reason

Comment: Thanks but like I said putting aside peoples opinions or truths about explicitly calling GC.Collect....

Comment: That locking code is also particularly pointless. What effect are you even trying to achieve here? (Pointless because two callers to this code will lock on two different objects)

Comment: @jquery auth: it's not an opinion. If you think you need to call GC.Collect() there is almost certainly something else wrong with your code.

Comment: @Damien: its a static. Poster has simplified the code

Comment: @Mitch - yeah, I kindof missed that, since it reads as a single block of code, which it can't, in fact, be, can it? First line belongs outside of any specific method.

Comment: @Mitch consider it to be more of a theoretical question. I just want to know if the above will\could deadlock, A debate about Garbage collection is exactly what I didn't want. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Major edit, so comments may seem out of place. Sorry for the inconvenience.

It is hard to tell for sure.

Assuming the code looks something like this

```
public class SomeType {
   private static readonly object Lock = new object();

   public void Foo() {
      lock (Lock) {
         Console.WriteLine("in foo");
         GC.Collect(2);
         GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
         GC.Collect(2);
      }
   }

   ~SomeType() {
      lock (Lock) {
         Console.WriteLine("in finalizer");
      }
   }
}
```

You could get a deadlock if you had more instances of `SomeType` as they all share a static object for locking. You need to have at least one unrooted and uncollected instance of `SomeType` and call `Foo` on another instance.

Now, if you don't have the finalizer as above, I can't see how the code could deadlock.

Comment: I edited the snippet, I don't actually lock on "this" it was just added to keep the example as small as possible

Comment: @Aliostad: Thanks for leaving a comment instead of just down voting. If the code above runs on a user thread and acquires the lock and then waits for the finalizer to run. Then if the finalizer tries to lock on the same object, it will block as this is already held by the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

No possibility of a deadlock. But why locking this? Why the second GC.Collect()?

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() is a blocking code so won't return until done. So I am not sure what you achive by locking.